# php - processing drag and drop navigation structure

Tags: php, navigation, parent

im trying to create a drag and drop (using jquery UI) navigation structure. I think I have done the jquery side which finds all the "pages" that have no child and work backwards to create a brach and all the branches are then past to the server.

lets say (on a small scale for testing) I get the following array after merging the branches:

```
Array
(
    [post-id-2] => Array
        (
            [post-id-5] => 
        )

    [post-id-3] => Array
        (
            [post-id-4] => post-id-1
        )

)
```

SO I now want to update my navigation table to set the correct pageid with page_parentid so I have tried the following but am getting nowhere:

```
$array = array();
$query_str = '';

foreach( $_POST['branch'] as $branch ) {
    eval('$array = array_merge( $array, ' . $branch . ');');        
}

function recrusive_parent_child( $parent, $array ) {
    $str = $parent;
    if( is_array( $array ) ) {
        foreach( $array as $parent => $branch ) {
            $str .= recrusive_parent_child( $parent, $branch );
        }
    }else{
        return $str;
    }
}

foreach( $array as $parent => $branch ) {
    echo recrusive_parent_child( $parent, $branch );
}

print_r($array);
die();
```

but only the original merged array is being displayed, nothing from the function. Can anyone give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: Why are you using eval in `eval('$array = array_merge( $array, ' . $branch . ');');`?  Why not just use `$array = array_merge( $array, $branch);`  Also can you please post the precise output of `print_r($array);` and `print_r($_POST);`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably that's because the array_merge does nothing, but that really depends on your input data. Let's take the first iteration of the foreach in your example, there the string that is passed to eval() is:

```
$array = array_merge( $array, Array);
```

This is because `$branch` is an array and an array casted to a string is "Array".

However, this should give you a "*syntax error in eval'd code*", because "array" is a reserved word and must be followed by "(".

You really should get rid of the *eval()*-solution. Post your desired result and we will help you find a proper solution.

Comment: the jquery builds a php array, eval just puts it into action